# How to process multiple input files and save the output in respective folders with filename as folder name using pyspark rdd

Tags: pyspark

I am having 5 input files say A,B,C,D,E. I want to load these files to a pyspark rdd and do some processing. Finally I want to save the output in a folder with the corresponding filename as folder name. Is this possible in spark cluster mode?

Comment: It should be possible to do this - is there a particular step you're stuck on?

Comment: While saving the output, how does spark rdd know the corresponding content of the file? How can we save the processed data in respective folders with filename?

Answer (score 0):

As the rdd/dataframe is essentially a bunch of rows distributed across multiple partitions you will lose track of the origin of the data after it is read in from multiple sources. So, my simplistic solution is to assign an additional value to the row which tracks its origin. Using the dataframe API:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from functools import reduce

fnames = ['file_A.csv','file_B.csv','file_C.csv']

dfs = []

# 1. Read in data from individual sources and assign the filename as a string to a column
for fname in fnames:
    dfs.append(spark.read.format('csv')
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .load(fname)
                    .withColumn('origin',lit(fname))
              )

# 2. Combine data 
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,dfs)

# +---+---+---+----------+
# |  A|  B|  C|    origin|
# +---+---+---+----------+
# |  1|  1|  1|file_A.csv|
# |  1|  1|  1|file_A.csv|
# |  1|  1|  1|file_A.csv|
# |  0|  0|  0|file_B.csv|
# |  0|  0|  0|file_B.csv|
# |  0|  0|  0|file_B.csv|
# |  2|  2|  2|file_C.csv|
# |  2|  2|  2|file_C.csv|
# |  2|  2|  2|file_C.csv|
# +---+---+---+----------+

# 3. Do processing
# ...

# 4. Subset the combined data by origin and write out each subset to file
for fname in fnames:
    
    out_fname = '_new.'.join(fname.split('.'))
    
    df.filter(col('origin')==fname)\
      .write.format('csv')\
      .option('header',True)\
      .save(out_fname)
```